# Need help sorting a textfile alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Okay So I'm need to take a list of unsorted words :

```
freddy
at
elephant
whoooooodat
alice
tommy
bobby
it
at
about
```

and sort it by length and alphabetically:

```
at
at
it
about
alice
bobby
tommy
freddy
elephant
whoooooodat
```

I can sort it with Collections.sort(words) and get:

```
at
it
at
alice
tommy
bobby
about
freddy
elephant
whoooooodat
```

I just need help alphabetizing the words.

Heres my current code:

```
public class Lab1
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("lab1.dat"));

        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        while(file.hasNext())
        {
            //add in a new Word to words
            words.add(new Word(file.next()));
        }

        //can sort the words with this 
        Collections.sort(words);


        //make letter lower case and compare asii values
        // need to sort the words by alphabetically 
        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size()-1 ; i++)
        {
            int min = i; 
            for(int j= i+1; j < words.size(); j++){
                String minstring = (String)words.get(min);
            if((((String)words.get(min)).toLowerCase()).compareTo(words.get(j)) > 0)
                min =j;



            }// end of inner loop

            if (min!= i){
            Word temp = words.get(min); 
            words.set(min,words.get(i));
            words.set(i,temp);
            }// end of sort if

        }   //end of outer loop
*/
        //print out words
        for (int j =0; j < words.size(); j++)
        System.out.println(words.get(j));
    }
}

 //Second Part
public class Word implements Comparable<Word>
{
    private String word;

    //constructors

    public Word()
    {
        word = "";
    }
    public Word(String a)
    {
        word =a;
    }



    //compareTo

    public int compareTo(Word other)
    {
        /*if (word.equals(other))
        {   
            if((word.charAt(0)).toLowerCase() )

        }*/
        return word.length() - other.word.length();
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return word;

    }

}
```

If you can help me that would be great...

Comment: your `compareTo(...)` method compares the values` length which means that your list will be sorted by size not alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compare-method should also implement alphabetical order:

```
public int compareTo(Word other)
    {
        int difference = word.length() - other.word.length();
        if(difference == 0){
            return word.compareToIgnoreCase(other.word);
        else{
            return difference;    
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! works great and Never really understood compareto in the first place.

Comment: compareTo Overrides the method from Comparable and is called for example by Collections.sort to decide which which Objects comes before another. You only return -1,0,1 wether the Objects are equal or different. Read the doc for more information :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {  
      if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
         return 1;
      } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
         return -1;
      }
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new MyComparator());
```